# Keeping track of child processes in Unix

Tags: c, unix, fork

I have finished a C program that spawns a number of processes and then kills them a short time later.  I am new to this and am trying to figure out why the way I am trying to keep track of my processes to kill works.  My pointer `pid_t* id` points to the number of process ids asked for by the cmd line argument as they are created.

Now here is my quandary.  fork() returns a value for both the child and parent, but I can't find if there is a fixed ordering on how it works.  Does it return the child or parent value first, or is it undefined?

The `id[]` array is the same for each spawned process, right(as in there are not n_child arrays being spawned)?

Since the program works 100% of the time, it seems that the parent is always returned last since that is what is stored in the array during the killing process.  Would this be a "safe" way to keep track of processes ( keep in mind i'm not looking for the best way or anything because I'm sure there are plenty better)?  It seems like the answer should be no, and that I should only set the array if I'm sure it's the parent.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX_N_CHILD 10

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int n_child, i;
  pid_t* id; 
  /* note: on a 32 bit machine, pid_t is defined as the __S32_TYPE,
     which is an int rather than a long */

  if (argc == 2) { 
    n_child = atoi (argv[1]); /* captures the command line argument */
    /* **NOTE** argv[0] is always the file name of this program */

    if (n_child > MAX_N_CHILD) {
      printf ("Too many children wanted!\n");
      return 0;
    }

  }
  else {
    printf ("Invalid number of arguments!\n");
    return 0;
  }

  id = malloc( sizeof(pid_t) * n_child );
  if(id == NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  printf ("********  HELLO!  *********\n");
  printf ("parent %d(CPU#%d)\n", getpid(), sched_getcpu());


  /* create new process(es) */
  for(i = 0; i < n_child; ++i)
  {
    id[i] = fork(); 

    if (id[i] == -1) 
    {
      printf("Error: Process not created");
      return 0;
    }
    else if (id[i] == 0) { /* I'm the child */
      //execlp ("./dummy", "dummy", NULL); /* replace myself with a new program */
      sleep(2);
    }
    else
    { 
      continue; //Continue loop
    }

  } //End for

      /* Only the parent process should get here. */

      /* wait a little to let the child processes run before killing them */
      usleep(50000); /* sleep for 50000 microseconds */


      /* kill */
      for(i = 0; i < n_child; ++i)
      {
        printf ("killing %d\n", id[i]);
        kill (id[i], SIGKILL); /* SIGKILL is defined in signal.h */
      }

      //pkill -TERM -P id  //Only kills immediate children of parent

      printf ("All %d child processes killed!\n", n_child);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now here is my quandary. fork() returns a value for both the child and parent, but I can't find if there is a fixed ordering on how it works. Does it return the child or parent value first, or is it undefined?

Um … no … not quite.

Here's what happens in `fork` (effectively):

- Your single process is *cloned* into an identical child process. Almost all of its attributes are copied.
- However, the child process will then have a new Process ID (pid)
- *In the child process,* `fork` returns a `0`.
- *In the parent process,* `fork` returns the child's new pid.

The two returns from `fork` occur *simultaneously,* in the two different copies of the process. Effectively, the only difference between them is what result they obtained from `fork`.

There is *no* ordering: these almost certainly ocuur on two CPU cores at the very same instant, and even on a single-core system, they will occur in *arbitrary* order and could potentially be executing single machine code instructions at a time, interleaved one with the other.

Put in a different light, the order is well-defined as being simultaneous.

At the moment of `fork`, there become two copies of everything. So, on the one hand, *yes*, there are now *n* copies of the array `id[]` in existence; however, each child's copy will have only the id's of the children spawned before it (and not even its own).

Replacing `exec` (`execlp` in this case) with `sleep` causes the program to wander into territory of being … very wierd. You write `/* Only the parent process should get here */`, but this is *not* true with `sleep`.

With `exec`* functions, you destroy the contents of a process and replace it (maintaining its pid and some other attributes) with a new program. Assuming that `exec` does not fail, then it's true, your program would no longer be the one in the child's process, and that line would not be reached;

However, as written, you have a curious race condition. The `sleep` and `usleep` may set a lower limit on how long the program will spend, but if for any reason the parent process did not move fast enough to kill its children, then the children will begin to attempt to (**edit** forgot this bit) finish out the `for` loop and spawn more children, and then kill one another and their new children. Since the `id[]` of each child was copied before it `fork`ed, then it will try to kill all its “older siblings” and then pid=0 for itself and the additional children which it has spawned.

You also mention spawning *threads* in your question, but nothing in your question's code has anything to do with threads.

Comment: I did not want to copy too much code into the window since it was a small problem.  So I just randomly put sleep(2) instead of another code block in case someone ran this. I understand this is not desirable.  Thank you for the answer.  And I meant processes, whoops..changing.

Answer (score 2):

I see one problem here. The line:

```
execlp ("./dummy", "dummy", NULL); /* replace myself with a new program */
```

was very important in your original program. If it is commented out, the child will continue the loop and spawning it's own sub-childs in the loop. So you will create (n*(n-1))/2 processes which then exits or are killed in a an unpredictable way.

Also your timing is very tight. Try to use delays in order of tens of seconds, so that you can manually watch what happens in your system.

Otherwise the program seems OK for me.

Concerning order of execution once the new process is created it competes for CPU in the same way as its parent process. So it is basically unpredictable which one will run first and for how long. If there are several cores in your CPU, they can actually run in the same time.

Comment: No no, as you can see the parent only waits 50,000 microseconds (0.05 sec) before it starts terminating.  The sleep(2) will wait 2 seconds for each child.  This is not the question, but I thank you.  The original program that linked to is a time wasting program for that cpu.  I'm only asking about fork(), how it works, and keeping track of child processes.  I do understand your sentiment though.

Comment: I'm specifically wondering why id[i] is always the id of a child (meaing set by a parent) and not 0 (meaning set by a child) at some places.  I think I am either getting lucky or I have a blatant misunderstanding of how the process works.

Comment: You can imagine that fork creates a new copy of the whole process including whole array `id`. So id[i] is set to 0 in the child's copy of the array. It is set to child's `pid` in the parents copy. Hence, the parent's `id` contains only pids of the child processes.

Comment: @user2079828 It is due to the way how `fork` works. Fork creates a copy of the whole process including copy of the heap (and your array `id`). If you use threads it would be different, because a new thread would share the array.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fork`, the parent and child processes each have their own copies of all variables; it effectively makes a snapshot of the parent process and copies it to the child. The two processes each run independently, and the `fork` function returns in *both* processes concurrently; in the parent it returns the PID of the child, in the child it returns 0.

So the ordering doesn't matter. Each process has its own `id` array, and they assign to their private copy of `id[i]`.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question.  I read that it made a "copy" of the source code, including PC and other things.  So basically, the malloc() of the id* pointer gets copied n times.